# Catch webhook node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, put, webhooks

I'm trying to catch a PUT/webhook request that is being made by the Aftership API in node.js. A PUT request is made each time a push notification is needed to be made, I am using Parse to send the notifications but I need some of the data from the webhook.

The header of the webhook looks like `Content-Type: application/json` And contains this data:

> ts - UTC unix timestamp that the event occurred
>
> event - the name of the event (for tracking update, the value will be
>   'tracking_update')
>
> msg - details about the message for which the event occurred, in the
>   following format.

How would I go about getting the tracking number, slug and the value for `token` in the custom fields dictionary in node or js?

```
{
    "event": "tracking_update",
    "msg": {
        "id": "53aa94fc55ece21582000004",
        "tracking_number": "906587618687",
        "title": "906587618687",
        "origin_country_iso3": null,
        "destination_country_iso3": null,
        "shipment_package_count": 0,
        "active": false,
        "order_id": null,
        "order_id_path": null,
        "customer_name": null,
        "source": "web",
        "emails": [],
        "custom_fields": {},
        "tag": "Delivered",
        "tracked_count": 1,
        "expected_delivery": null,
        "signed_by": "D Johnson",
        "shipment_type": null,
        "tracking_account_number": null,
        "tracking_postal_code": "DA15BU",
        "tracking_ship_date": null,
        "created_at": "2014-06-25T09:23:08+00:00",
        "updated_at": "2014-06-25T09:23:08+00:00",
        "slug": "dx",
        "unique_token": "xk7LesjIgg",
        "checkpoints": [{
            "country_name": null,
            "country_iso3": null,
            "state": null,
            "city": null,
            "zip": null,
            "message": "Signed For by: D Johnson",
            "coordinates": [],
            "tag": "Delivered",
            "created_at": "2014-06-25T09:23:11+00:00",
            "checkpoint_time": "2014-05-02T16:24:38",
            "slug": "dx"
        }]
    },
    "ts": 1403688191
}
```

Comment: is this JSON sent in the body of the PUT request?

Comment: @akonsu Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with `Express` framework, example:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express(),
    port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    var trackingNumber = body.msg.tracking_number;
    var slug = body.msg.slug;
    var token = body.msg.unique_token;

    console.log(trackingNumber, slug, token);

    res.json({
        message: 'ok got it!'
    });
});

var server = app.listen(port, function () {

    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
```

Here is the [GIT repository](https://github.com/hellowin/example-expressjs-aftership-webhook), just clone it and do `npm install` and then `npm start`. The server will run on port `3000` :D

Note: I saw in Aftership Webhook's documentation, it said they will request `POST` HTTP method, not `PUT` so I create an example of `post` request. Just replace it with `put` if you want it to catch `put` request.

Comment: No this is not right, each request is different. The JSON provided is just an example of what will be coming in.

Comment: So the JSON is the returned body via some endpoint and you ask how to get it? Is the endpoint is something that you already available to get? If yes, so you ask how to hit that endpoint and manipulate the result?

Comment: Yes. This JSON is sent as a PUT request. I want to know how I can get the JSON from the put request and then your manipulate it. Your manipulation seems to be right, but the JSON part is static.

Comment: What framework do you use? NodeJS with Express? Because the answer is depends on how to create a request. If you don't mind, please let me know how do you create that request, so I will understand where is the `callback` result goes.

Comment: The request is not created by me, it is sent by an API. This is the short documentation for the webhook. https://www.aftership.com/docs/api/4/webhook

Comment: Oh I got it, so you want to create a `webhook` to catch a json that requested to it. It can be done trough Express, wait a little longer if you will, I will try give an example and also GitHub code so you can easily just do `npm install` in your development server.

Comment: For some reason whenever I try to set my destination URL to my URL I get an error of. `The webhook responses is incorrect. HTTP RESPONSE CODE: 404`  What I am doing is using Parses starter Javascript project and then using their free hosting to host the files.

Comment: are you sure it reach port `3000`? try to change the port to `80`, so it will listen default HTTP port.

Comment: It's just `front end` HTML, no it can't do that way. It should use NodeJS, not just static HTML files. Because you need to `catch` POST (or PUT) request so you must provide webserver. It can be done trough plain HTML with Javascript like that. Think PHP, NodeJS is webserver like that :)

Comment: I mean, "it can't be done" :D you must provide webserver that can catch POST or PUT request.

Answer (score 3):

For inspecting webhooks data, I would suggest to store every request in database and then query database. As each request is different, easiest way would be creating API in sails.js (Node.js framework with easy to use ORM).

```
sudo npm install sails -g
sails new _project_name_
cd _project_name_
sails generate api Records
```

With last command, sails has generated controller and model to store your webhook data.

I suggest installing pm2 for running app. you can run it with

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Next you should configure your webhook in Aftership for following url:

YOUR_SERVER_IP:PORT/Records/create

you can inspect data by following url:

YOUR_SERVER_IP:PORT/Records/find

if you want to parse data, it can be done in RecordsController.js, for example:

```
Parsing: function(req, res) {

    Records.find({}).exec(function(err, results) {

        var output = [];

        while (results.length) {
            var result = results.pop();
            //custom parsing goes here
            //example:
            output.push({
                tracking_number: result.msg.tracking_number,
                slug: result.msg.slug,
                unique_token: result.msg.unique_token
            });
        }
        return res.json(output);
    });


},
```

You can call this method via following url:
YOUR_SERVER_IP:PORT/Records/Parsing

I have created project in Codeanywhere for demonstration

webhook endpoint is:
http://port-1337.zavtt4t8a0jm7vigncyo3txxmuhxgvix3yxk66pvydgqfr.box.codeanywhere.com/records/create

For inspecting data, just replace /create part of url to /find

git repo is here: https://github.com/dkatavic/webhook_for_aftership

you can just clone the project on your server and run it (or use my server for testing)

Answer (score 1):

You can catch PUT request by

```
app.put('/someRouteToCatchWebHook', function(request, response) {
  //webhook parsing goes here
});
```

(i'm sure that you use expressjs in your code - see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.METHOD for details).

If the webhook data is in request body, you can use  the https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser module for parsing it.

Comment: I have very little experience with JS/HTML. I have sued npm to install express. But now how do I included the express framework into my HTML file?

Comment: @Nick You can't Include express in a HTML file. NodeJS is a platform to run javascript, express is a framewrok for NodeJS to serve websites (HTML). After looking at the code you linked in Andi's answer, I'm not even sure what you're trying to do anymore.